# Custom Handler for UWP MediaElementPlayer FullWindow

Tags: c#, uwp, event-handling, controls

I would like to have a custom handler for the  `FullWindowButton` in `MediaPlayerElement`.  I've created a `CustomMediaTransportControls` similar to Microsoft's example project.  I've created an event handler for the `FullWindowButton` by doing the following in my code:

```
Button fullWindowButton = GetTemplateChild("FullWindowButton") as Button;
fullWindowButton.Click += FullWindowButton_Click;
```

The event gets triggered when entering and leaving `FullWindowMode`, but I'm not sure how to prevent `MediaPlayerElement` from handling the `FullWindowButton` change.  Is there a way to do this or should I create a seperate, custom `FullWindow` button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a great guide on implementing and modifying the `CustomMediaTransportControls` manually in the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/custom-transport-controls).

I would suggest you to hide the default full screen button and then add a custom app bar button with your desired functionality, because although it is possible to prevent the default action from executing (by clearing all event handlers), but it is not a "clean" solution.

You can add your custom button to the `CommandBar` within the template and then attach a custom `Click` handler inside the `OnApplyTemplate` override.